# Select specific column in laravel eloquent's with method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using `laravel 5.6` and i want to get user `posts` with `comments` (only `id` field)

**User Model**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

**Post Model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

**Comment Model**

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

In my controller i am using this code to get user posts with their comments

```
$posts = $request->user()->posts()->with(['comments' => function($query) {
    $query->select(['id']);
}]);
```

But its not working...

When i comment `$query->select(['id']);` it works fine but returns `Comment` model all fields. I want to only select `id` field.

What i am missing here?

Comment: Do you get any errors ?

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin no it returns null

Comment: try $query->select('id')

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin Already tried...

Comment: what about this $request->user()->posts->with(['comments' => function($query)

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin Please look the question. i am already using this ;-)

Comment: post doesn't have ()

Comment: This will return Error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172631/discussion-between-masoud-haghbin-and-saeed-vaziry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to select the foreign key column (required for matching the results):

```
$posts = $request->user()->posts()->with('comments:id,post_id');
```

Comment: it doesnt work if your required column is only `name`!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to only one column, you can use `->pluck('id')`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck

Comment: pluck gets only the value of field.